# why do I get segmentation fault in this code?

Tags: segmentation-fault

this code finds minimum number for five numbers.
I want to return (int type)min_value's address, but have runtime-error, segmentation fault
how can I solve this error help me

---

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#include <stdio.h>
int min(int ar[]);

int main() {

    int array[5];
    int min_address = 0, min_value = 0;
    int* Np, * Np1;
    Np1 = &min_value;
    for (Np = array; Np < array + 5; Np++) {
        scanf("%d", Np);
    }

    min_address = min(array);
    Np1 = (int*)min_address;
    printf("%d", *Np1);
    Np1++;
    printf("%d", *Np1);
    return 0;
}
```

```
int min(int ar[]) {
`enter code here`

    int* p = ar;
    int min, minidx = 0;
    min = *p;
    int i = 0, address;
    for (p = ar; p < ar + 5; p++, i++) {
        if (*p == 0) break;
    enter code here

        if (min > * p) {
            min = *p;
            minidx = i;
        }
    }
    address = ar + minidx;
    return address;
}
```